# No window or view controller in Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: macos, xcode, cocoa

I am new to macOS programming, I have Xcode 11.2.1  and Catalina OS. What is strange is I look at tutorials online and they all have Window and view controller in main storyboard, I only have menu there.

Also tutorials have "Cocoa app" under templates for Mac OS, when I choose it, there is only "app" option. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tick "use storyboards" in new project window, not `SwiftUI`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui

[image: Xcode new project]

Comment: Actually there is not "use storyboards" to tick, but to select for user interface storyboard instead of swift UI, does it. What is the difference, I mean can i still make window controller with swift UI and when should I use swift UI and when storyboards?

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic I never used this.. Please post a new question. You might want to read the link I mentioned.